# Accessing pointer from array of pointer inside a struct results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, list, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I'm having difficulties on trying to access the members of `item_t` pointers from the `**addr` variable in `cart_t`. The definition of `cart_t` is as follows:

```
typedef struct cart_struct {
    item_t **addr;
    int ptr;
    float total;
} cart_t;
```

I have initialized and add items to the `**addr` using the following code:

```
cart_t *cart_append_item(cart_t *cart, item_t *item) {
    if (cart == NULL || item == NULL)
        return NULL;

    item_t **new = (item_t**) malloc(sizeof(item_t*) * (cart->ptr + 1));

    if (new == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<cart->ptr; i++) {
        new[i] = cart->addr[i];
    }

    new[i+1] = item;

    if (cart->addr != NULL) {
        free(cart->addr);
    }

    cart->addr = new;

    cart->ptr += 1;
    printf("price %f, quantity %d, total %f\n", new[cart->ptr]->price, new[cart->ptr]->quantity, new[cart->ptr]->price * new[cart->ptr]->quantity); // this works.
    //printf("total_prev %f\n", cart->total);
    cart->total += item->price * item->quantity;
    //printf("total %f\n", cart->total);

    return cart;
}
```

As you can see on the code above, the debug `printf` actually works. But when I try to do it later on the `cart.addr[n]`, it results in segmentation fault:

```
// cart_t canteen_cart
// item_t *item_current
...
if (cart_append_item(&canteen_cart, item_current) == NULL) {
    // error. clean up
}
...
printf("[TEST] price %f, quantity %d, total %f\n", canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->price, canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->quantity, canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->price * canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->quantity); // segmentation fault
...
```

Thanks!

---

Snippets of the `int main()`:

```
int main() {
    cart_t canteen_cart;
    canteen_cart.addr = NULL;
    canteen_cart.ptr = 0;
    canteen_cart.total = 0.0f;

    item_t *item_current = NULL;

    ...
    a hundred of lines later of user input thingy
    ...

    if (state == STATE_CHECKOUT) {
        printf("[TEST] %d\n", canteen_cart.addr == NULL); // returns 0
        printf("[TEST] %d\n", canteen_cart.ptr > 0); // returns 1, there are some items in the array
        printf("price %f, quantity %d, total %f\n", canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->price, canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->quantity, canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->price * canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->quantity);
    print_view_checkout(&canteen_cart); // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
    }

    cart_free_items(&canteen_cart); // free cart and all the members within it.

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It seems you might need to learn about [*`realloc`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: As for your problem, when and where is the variable `canteen_cart` defined? How is it initialized? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I was considering to use `realloc`, but I continued with `malloc`-`free` pair instead...

Comment: realloc will move the contents of the list for you so you dont have to copy the contents in a loop as you do now.

Comment: Why? Because right now you might actually have *undefined behavior* by dereferencing a null or uninitialized pointer in your copying. Something which would not happen if you used `realloc`. And the (potential) copying of `realloc` is probably more optimized than your loop.

Comment: `int ptr;` Well, that is a beautiful name for a variable intended to contain the element count.

Comment: Oh, and I really recommend you use a debugger to catch the crash, or at least step through the code line by line, because you have a definitive off-by-one error leading you to write out of bounds of your allocated memory.

Comment: [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) is my go-to tool to solve memory errors like this. (segfault is a memory violation error)

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset: `valgrind` said `Invalid read of size 4` followed by `Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd` on the line `printf("price %f, quantity %d, total %f\n", canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->price, canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->quantity, canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->price * canteen_cart.addr[canteen_cart.ptr-1]->quantity);`... I don't understand, the it should have been initialized...

Comment: `Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd` this means you are trying to read from address `0x10`. One of your pointers is bogus.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset I've probably fixed that but now this happened: `valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal`

Comment: welp, then you need to use a debugger or just print more to see what is going on. Learn this the hard way. Use google.

Comment: Well, my fault, I mistakenly `realloc` with 1 as the new size... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now when we can see how you initialize `canteen_cart`, take this *single* line from the `cart_append_item` function:

```
new[i+1] = item;
```

In the very first call to the `cart_append_item` function, the value of `cart->ptr` (it is indeed badly named) is `0`. That means the loop will not iterate and the value of `i` will be zero. That means you in effect is doing `new[1] = item`, where `new` only has space for a single element with index `0`. This writing out of bounds of course leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), making your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid. And prone to crashing.

You continue to write out of bounds for each consecutive call to `cart_append_item` as well.

The simple solution? Use `new[cart->ptr] = item` instead.

---

Then regarding my `realloc` comment, you can make the function so much shorter and simpler if using `realloc`:

```
cart_t *cart_append_item(cart_t *cart, item_t *item) {
    if (cart == NULL || item == NULL)
        return NULL;

    item_t **new_items = realloc(cart->addr, sizeof *cart->addr * cart->ptr + 1);
    if (new_items == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    cart->addr = new_items;

    // Add the new item
    cart->addr[cart->ptr++] = item;

    cart->total += item->price * item->quantity;

    return cart;
}
```